How to fetch IdeaProject Gradle Model in Java?
I make a simple Android IDE for android system but ProjectConnection not working
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.attachCallerThreadStackTrace(BlockingResultHandler.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:51)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultProjectConnection.getModel(DefaultProjectConnection.java:58)
    at com.gradle.builder.Main.main(Main.java:23)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.FilteringClassLoader.<clinit>(FilteringClassLoader.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.createImplementationClassLoader(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:117)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.create(DefaultToolingImplementationLoader.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.CachingToolingImplementationLoader.create(CachingToolingImplementationLoader.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.loader.SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.create(SynchronizedToolingImplementationLoader.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.onStartAction(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:160)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:142)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not determine java version from '0'.
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.assertTrue(JavaVersion.java:298)
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.convertToNumber(JavaVersion.java:316)
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.toVersion(JavaVersion.java:147)
    at org.gradle.api.JavaVersion.current(JavaVersion.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.<clinit>(ClassLoaderUtils.java:38)
    ... 17 more

public static void main(String[] args) {        final File GRADLE_USER_HOME_DIR = new File(args[0]);      final File PROJECT_DIR = new File(args[1]);       GradleConnector connector = GradleConnector.newConnector();         connector.forProjectDirectory(PROJECT_DIR);         connector.useGradleUserHomeDir(GRADLE_USER_HOME_DIR);                       try {           ProjectConnection connection = connector.connect();             long timeStart = System.nanoTime();             System.out.println("Building Project...");          IdeaProject ideaProject = connection.getModel(IdeaProject.class);           System.out.format("BUILD SUCCESSFUL in %ds", (System.nanoTime() - timeStart) / 1000000000L);            ObjectUtils.writeObject(new Project(ideaProject), new File(PROJECT_DIR, "IdeaProject.obj").getAbsolutePath());      } catch (Exception e) {             e.printStackTrace();            System.err.println(e.getMessage());         }   }   static class Project implements Serializable {          public String name;         public Project(IdeaProject project) {           this.name = project.getName();          }   }
Used Code : 
